# Actionscript Datagrid ItemEditor with different types than type of DataGridColumn value

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, datagrid, combobox

I have a DataGrid where one column has a `ComboBox` as an item editor for one of the columns.  The type of values in the `ComboBox`'s `dataProvider` are different from the type of value that is stored in the cell being edited.  How can I map the value returned by the item editor to the value in the cell.  A complete example illustrating my problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               creationComplete="init()">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

        [Bindable]
        private var items:ArrayCollection;

        [Bindable]
        public var foobar:ArrayCollection;

        private function init():void
        {
            items = new ArrayCollection();
            items.addItem({name : "Adam", abbrev: "ABCD"});
            items.addItem({name : "Frank", abbrev : "EFGH"});
            items.addItem({name:"Bob", abbrev:"ABCD"});

            foobar = new ArrayCollection();
            foobar.addItem({id:"ABCD", displayValue:"Adam Buys Cheap Drinks"});
            foobar.addItem({id:"EFGH", displayValue:"Eban Flies Great Heat"});
        }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <mx:DataGrid dataProvider="{items}" editable="true">
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Name" dataField="name" />
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Abbrev" dataField="abbrev"
                               editorDataField="selectedItem">
                <mx:itemEditor>
                    <fx:Component>
                        <mx:ComboBox labelField="displayValue"
                                     dataProvider="{outerDocument.foobar}" />
                    </fx:Component>
                </mx:itemEditor>
            </mx:DataGridColumn>
        </mx:columns>
    </mx:DataGrid>
</s:Application>
```

What I want to see happen is that when the user picks an item from the `ComboBox`, that the `id` attribute of the value returned is placed in the cell being edited in the grid.

As it stands the id/displayValue object is passed instead, resulting in `[object object]` being displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case it will be enough to change `editorDataField="selectedItem"` to `editorDataField="selectedLabel"`. If you want to have more complex itemEditor (for example, add some text automatically) than you can do next:

```
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Abbrev" dataField="abbrev">
            <mx:itemEditor>
                <fx:Component>
                    <mx:ComboBox labelField="displayValue"
                                 dataProvider="{outerDocument.foobar}">
                        <fx:Script>
                            <![CDATA[
                            override public function get value():Object
                            {
                                return selectedLabel + "some example text";
                            }
                            ]]>
                        </fx:Script>
                    </mx:ComboBox>
                </fx:Component>
            </mx:itemEditor>
        </mx:DataGridColumn>
```

And last one - [good article](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/itemeditors_pt1.html) about itemEditors (most about it I took there).
In method `get value` you can return anything and this will be shown on DataGrid.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create own item editor based on `ComboBox` class and implement property that will return id of selected item. Something like this:

```
public function get selectedItemId():String {
    if (selectedItem) {
         return selectedItem.id;
    } else {
         return null;
    }
}
```

Then you should set this new property `selectedItemId` as `editorDataField` in `DataGridColumn`.